# why is window.location.href eliminating the hash value

Tags: jquery

I have an issue that I am facing right now.

```
console.log('location.href', window.location.href);
```

I only get `location.href – "https://my.domain.here.com/expertise/referenzen/#"`

yet the URL in the browser reads `location.href – "https://my.domain.here.com/expertise/referenzen/#produktion-mittelstaendischer-hersteller"`.

i have even gone ahead and logged window.location

```
[Log] Location (tb_custom.js, line 19)

ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList {length: 0, item: function, contains: function}

assign: function()

hash: "#produktion-mittelstaendischer-hersteller"

host: "my.domain.here.com"

hostname: "my.domain.here.com"

href: "https://my.domain.here.com/expertise/referenzen/#produktion-mittelstaendischer-hersteller"

origin: "https://my.domain.here.com"

pathname: "/expertise/referenzen/"

port: ""

protocol: "https:"

reload: function()

replace: function()

search: ""

toString: function()

valueOf: function()

Symbol(Symbol.toPrimitive): undefined

Location Prototype
```

I can get the value for window.location.pathname and other things there apart from the hash value even when I call href. The URL comes without the hash value.

why is this happening?

**Update**: Another thing I have noticed is that the value of hash will be shown if the anchor/hash value is not on the page hence it won't scroll down to where the anchor is. I am suspecting this could be related to the issue but I don't know why hence cannot yet come up with a remedy.

Comment: If you want access to the hash, you will need to get `window.location.hash`

Comment: @Terry as I said before when I try to access it that way nothing gets logged unless the values of the hash are not an id on that page. I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have spent some time on this trying to understand what is happening and it seems like by the time I try to get the hash value there is none and script is doing something else. so my workaround was to create a loop and add a simple delay or timeout and wait until when there is a  value for location.hash. Here is the code am using for it

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {

    let current_hash_value = location.hash;

    let check = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (current_hash_value === null) {

                check();
            } else {
                var hash_value_after_wait = window.location.hash;
                $j(hash_value_after_wait).trigger("click"); //just to click and open accordion
                console.log(hash_value_after_wait);
            }
        }, 500);
    };
    check();
});
```

Hope it helps someone else too.